# query datatable sorting not working for run time values

Tags: php, jquery

I used jquery data table for sorting. It works fine under normal condition. If i changed the value in run time, the sorting is not working.

This is my table data

```
<table width="94%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" class="tablehead" id="pls-batting">
  <thead>     
    <tr class="tab_head" align="right" id="pls-play" >
      <th width="44" align="center" ># No </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr  id="116706">
      <td align="left" id='1' >test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="116707">
      <td align="left" id='2'>bbb</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="116708">
      <td align="left" id='3' >xxx</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Jquery method used for sorting is :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#pls-batting').dataTable( {

        } );
 } );
```

By clicking the '# No' head the corresponding column displayed in asc and desc order respectively. These TD values will be changed onload by using

```
    document.getElementById(3).innerHTML = 'something';
```

So as a result the 3rd column value is 'something'. So sorting will be done by this values. But it is not working.

It takes the old values. Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After changing the value of the table with javascript, you need to redraw the table:

```
$('#pls-batting').dataTable();
document.getElementById(3).innerHTML = 'something';
$('#pls-batting').fnDraw();
```

As a side note: a numeric id is not valid. It has to start with an alpha character, e.g. `a1`

Comment: I tried this one $('#pls-batting').fnDraw(); also. But it is not working. What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you redrawing the table _after_ you manipulated the values via javascript?

Comment: Yes i used the fnDraw() function after i changed the value in javascript

Comment: Maybe you can put the whole thing in a js fiddle, otherwise it's next to impossible for us to guess the exact error

Comment: I am using fnUpdate instead of innerHTML. Now it is fixed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @SamHanson `fnUpdate` is the only way that worked for me, thanks. I think you should add this as a new answer (and accept it). Reference: http://datatables.net/api

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, is there any reason you're using:

`document.getElementById(3).innerHTML = 'something';`

rather than:

```
$('#3').html('something');
```

If there's no reason for that then change it and try again. If that doesn't work then once you've changed the value to something reinitialise dataTable again by doing:

`$('#pls-batting').dataTable( {
    // options here
} );`

as the function probably caches the table values and positions so it doesn't have to traverse the DOM every time you do a sort.

Comment: read the comment below, rather than reinitialising the entire function do as konsolenfreddy says and redraw the table using $('#pls-batting').fnDraw();.

Answer (score 0):

You should redraw the table. The best thing is to cache the datatable like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var oTable = $('#pls-batting').dataTable() ;
  document.getElementById(3).innerHTML = 'something';
  oTable.fnDraw();
 } );
```

Comment: I used the oTable.fnDraw() . But it is not working. Shall i do any update functionality?